# Same code base in different apps

Tags: ios, xcode

Here's my problem: Today my company has an app that communicates with a specific server, but we received demands to develop this same App for different servers, so a few things need to be changed in the App (like the URL to call and the logo).

I do not want to create a whole new application with 99% of the code the same in my Xcode just to do that, because it would be really difficult to develop new stuff.

I'm wondering if it's possible to maintain the same base code with just small changes to different applications.

Hope I made myself clear, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a guide somewhere describing how to do that?

Comment: Just put all the server-specific stuff in a configurable resource and make the actual code suitably generic.

Comment: Put then I still have to create different applications in xcode, right? Because it will be different apps in the app store.

Somehow, I would like to reuse the same "core", to my new stuff be applied on all the apps at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @ViniciusPaiva. That's actually the right answer to your question. You've asked a very broad, general question, without doing enough research and reading documentations beforehand. These sort of questions can be asked in forums or chatrooms rather than SO. For asking a question here, you should do something first, show your code, your error and then try to get help. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry about that Neeku. I also asked this same question in the apple technical support. I'm was just assuming that would be a guide somewhere for doing that, I couldn't find.

Now I know why I'm receiving so many down votes =P

Comment: Well, the fact with these websites is that they won't teach you how to become a programmer. They'll help you with the issues that you have as a programmer. I'm providing some sort of answer down there, hoping that helps, but you should provide better details in your questions in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, I just found this guide:

https://itexico.com/blog/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code

Different targets and preprocessor macros are just what I needed, pretty sweet!

Answer (score -1):

For something like this, I'd suggest using easy-to-manipulate stuff like `plist`s and so on to make a core app like a framework that would be able to read an `XML` for example, and parse its data into different fields of your `Plist` and apply the settings based on that data for every new app that you have.

So, you should have items like `url` and `logo`, etc. in your settings Plist, and getting to read them in the app rather than setting values manually inside the app. This way, you'll be able to drop different image files called `logo.png` for each app, or edit the value for `url` in your Plist, and the app will read the value from the Plist.

However keep in mind that Plists are good if you don't have a giant list of items, because they can be slow if you get a really big one, but they're so quick and handy for average number of items.

I hope this helps.