# Submit multiple iOS apps with same code base

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I'm trying to develop an app that can be used to generate multiple apps. Let's say for now I'm doing an app for fruits, but tomorrow the client will want to create an app for vegetables, and the day after tomorrow for meats, and so on.

So what I'm doing right now is creating an app with same codebase and generating different Targets for each topic (fruits, vegetables, etc.) with its own settings.

That is working really good for now, but I want to make sure that my apps all passes the [AppStore review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). The one that concerns me is this one:

> 4.3 Spam
>   Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has different versions for specific locations, sports teams, universities, etc., consider submitting a single app and provide the variations using in-app purchase. Also avoid piling on to a category that is already saturated; the App Store has enough fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps already. Spamming the store may lead to your removal from the Developer Program.

So I've read some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084419/same-code-base-in-different-apps) that talks about the best way to accomplish doing multiple apps with same codebase, but hadn't seen anyone lately talking about the Apple restriction to this stuff.

If using different targets it's not a solution for Apple to approve, and you know one, I'll be glad to hear it! What I wanna avoid is making one app and make the user select the type of food he wants (following my example scenario). So my goal is having multiple apps for all different topics, and make Apple approve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is great question. I hope someone from apple team can answer this correctly.

My personal experience

1. Creation of separate app is perfectly fine as long as end app provides something unique compare to other bundleId. In my case We have 100+laws apps having each law app created using same code base but different data and from User perspective they need it in separate app compared to grouped app.
2. The visual schema should be different in each application. Please try to make different colors, logos, URL's / data for each flavor.
3. Each app name-should be unique ( Apple doesn't allow you sell app with same name). Adding hypen, or cosmetic name changes will be definitely candidate for app rejection.
4. Having said that there is no gurantee to get your app approved each time. In appeal also if you try to tell them that similar app is approved, you are at their mercy to get it approved.