# Rebrending iOS app and releasing it to apple store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have built iOS app and I want to rebrand it. Mainly, on most screens, I want to make changes on colors, images and maybe an additional view or two.

In total, I would have 3 similar apps that I want to release. **The other 2  will be registered with a other company name as owner.**

- Do I have to register for 2 different apple developer program accounts? or I can manage this with single account?

**EDIT**

What i have tried so far - Volume Purchase Program - this doesn't seem to cut it, i want to have apps on apple store. It seems through this program apps are distributed somewhat privately.

I know i can release multiple rebranded apps under different name from same iTunnes account - but than will they be registered under same company name as owner? **I need them registered with different company name as owner.**

Comment: You don't need a separate account. Creating separate account doesn't give any assurance of app approval/rejection. 

Please see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296597/submit-multiple-ios-apps-with-same-code-base/39297195#39297195

Comment: @MegaManX Answer to your question 1. Yes you can manage with single account.  2. Yes you are apple's mercy, there is no gurantee to get it approved ( my experience you can't argue either , giving example of already approved app doesn't help either ). As long as each app adds a value compare to previous app, i don't see a reason of rejection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do need two developer programs, because

> I need them registered with different company name as owner.

You can't achieve it with a single developer program account, unfortunately.

UPDATE: you still can use @Ahmad's solution with multiple targets (nothing wrong with that), but you do need to register 2 times in the Apple Developer Program (or, maybe, one is your own, another one belongs to a company).

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to register for 2 different apple developer program
>   accounts? or I can manage this with single account?

No you don't have to. It's optional to have more than one account in case if customers want to have their own saperated accounts. You can achieve this by making **Multiple Targets** on the same project (customize the UI and integrated servers for example) and distribute each one on different a **Bundle Identifier**. *You can find dozens of article about how to make multiple targets*.

Even if each target has to be on a separated account, you can easily do that by assigning the developer team for it.

[image]

Hope that helped.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @FreeNickname for noticing that
"*The other 2 will be registered with a other company name as owner*" is required. In this case, yes you have to enroll with more than 1 program as @FreeNickname answered.