# Converting Existing App to B2B App

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning, b2b

I have developed an iPhone App. My Company wants to sell it to a Customer. It is a B2B App. I know how to submit the App as B2B App. But my problem is, Can I anyway upload the app to the App Store as a normal app and then if I want, can I submit the same app as a B2B app with a different App id or bundle id?

It will be great that if somebody can give me an answer

Comment: yes, you can submit the same app using diffrent bundle id the apple would count as another app.

Comment: Thank You, so i no need to do any change to the app. but i need to use different bundle id when i want to submit the app as B2B ?. and what about the App name and other stuffs ?

Comment: yes, you have to choose another name and you can also do some tricks like if name is **TestApp** so just change it to **TestApp.** add dot or **Test  App1** whatever you like...

Comment: Thank you @ravi.p i will try this

Comment: Welcome..@Darshana  :)

Comment: simply changing the name will end up in rejecting app. Always follow apple guidelines for creating flavour builds to your apps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296597/submit-multiple-ios-apps-with-same-code-base/39297195#39297195