# Multiple developer accounts selling same app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I saw that some companies publish the same app 3 to 5 times with different names and colors, but with the same functionality, UI design and even description. Also, they have 4 or 5 developer accounts with different names (a few individual and few company accounts). In total this companies have 20-30 copies of the same app (with different colors) in the App Store.
My question is it okay or it against the rules and fault of App Store moderators? Does Apple have any regulation for it? This situation looks like unfair competition to other apps.

The only thing I found in guidelines is:

> 2. Functionality
>
> 2.11 Apps that duplicate Apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra Apps

Maybe someone know some more about it? I would be glad to hear your thoughts.

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296597/submit-multiple-ios-apps-with-same-code-base/39297195#39297195

Comment: you can have same functionality app compare to other, provided it's not exact duplicate and gives some additional functionality or uniqueness to your app